# How to toggle boolean state in React and TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am new to React and TypeScript.

I want to toggle a boolean state (true/false) with a handler function. I've read other posts about how to do this in ES6 but I am unclear of how to achieve this in TypeScript.

So far I have:

```
  const MyComponent = () => {
    const [collapseUpper, setCollapseUpper] = React.useState(true);

    const handleCollapse = () => {
      collapseUpper = !setCollapseUpper;
    };

    return (
       <Link onClick={handleCollapse}>More</Link>
       <Collapse in={collapseUpper}>
         //content
```

But I cannot get it to work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `setCollapseUpper` is a function not a value

Comment: You need to invoke it `setCollapseUpper(!collapseUpper)`

Comment: Read here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how it should be done:

```
const handleCollapse = () => {
  setCollapseUpper(!collapseUpper);
};
```

You will need to call the `setCollapseUpper` to handle any updates in state.

Better still, you can use the callback function to update the state:

```
const handleCollapse = () => {
  setCollapseUpper((prevState) => !prevState);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the value of `collapseUpper` not `setCollapseUpper`:

```
const [collapseUpper, setCollapseUpper] = React.useState(true);

const handleCollapse = () => {
  setCollapseUpper(!collapseUpper);
};
```